# How to add a variable in jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I'm trying to add a variable while getting the info from a JSON file as shown below.

```
stack=$(cat profiles.json | jq '.generic.category')

email=$(cat profiles.json | jq '.central.[Need to add $stack variable here].email')
echo $email
password=$(cat profiles.json | jq '.central.[Need to add $stack variable here].password')
echo $password
```

I tried few things like `jq --arg v $stack '.central[$v]password*'` but it didnt work.

This is what my the profiles.json looks like:

```
  "central": {
        "one": {
            "tenant": "xxx-yyy-zzz",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
            "password": "1111"
         },
        "two": {
            "tenant": "aaa-bbb-ccc",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
            "password": "2222"
         }
  },
  "generic": {
        "username": "root",
        "password": "xyz",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "two"
    }
```

What is the right command to fetch the required information using the variable?

Comment: Please try adding quotes `--arg v "$stack"`.

Comment: @pmf I tried that, getting the below error            **email_f=$(cat profiles.json | jq --arg v "$stack" '.central[$v]email')**
echo $email               **ERROR:jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.central[$v]email            
jq: 1 compile error**

Comment: `'.central[$v]email'` - you're missing a period before email.

Comment: Have you considered using `jq -r '.central[.generic.category].email' profiles.json`? [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CQd_o46Vlku)

Comment: Perfect!! These things helped, its working now

Comment: @pmf Great, this is what I have been looking for..

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat profiles.json
{
   "central": {
        "one": {
            "tenant": "xxx-yyy-zzz",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
            "password": "1111"
         },
        "two": {
            "tenant": "aaa-bbb-ccc",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
            "password": "2222"
         }
  },
  "generic": {
        "username": "root",
        "password": "xyz",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "two"
    }
}

$ jq --arg MYVAR one '.central[$MYVAR].password' profiles.json
"1111"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do without the shell variable `stack`, unless you want to use it in different places later in your shell script.

```
email=$(jq -r '.central[.generic.category].email' profiles.json)
echo $email
password=$(jq -r '.central[.generic.category].password' profiles.json)
echo $password
```